# @Schedule annotation in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, ejb, scheduled-tasks

I use the following annotation to call a stateless session bean once a 5 minutes:

```
@Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0/5", hour = "*")
```

I works as expected, except it stops itself after a few days. I guess there may be a default lifetime and I do not know how to override it.

Please help me to configure the scheduler to run indefinitely.

Comment: The annotation looks correct (note, second="0" is the default and does not need to be specified), and there should not be a maximum lifetime.  Which application server are you using?  Are there any errors in the logs to suggest it might have failed?  Is it possible that the application calls Timer.cancel on the automatically created timer?

Comment: I use Glassfish v3, and I could not find errors in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

to know if there is expiration date for your object you can use getTimers() to return an object of that timer then use this method `getTimeRemaining()` to know if there is expiration date for it.

anyway, you can use this annotation `@Timeout` to do something in case of timeout happens :

```
@Timeout
public void timeout(Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("do something ... ");
}
```

you can print the date here to know when the timeout happens..

another thing you are using "Automatic Timers" and it's configured at **ejb-jar.xml** so try to take a look at **ejb-jar.xml** to see if there is expiration date there ..

Answer (score 1):

In Glassfish under Configuration -> server-config -> EJB-Container -> EJB-Timeservice new property: reschedule-failed-timer = true

Answer (score 0):

Your @Schedule annotation look correct, so first thing you should check is logs and see if there are exceptions in your scheduled methods.

As per specification if an exception is thrown inside a Timer method, that method will be called once more and if it fails again the timer is shut down.