# Vaadin7 Container Updates from Server - To use server push or not

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I wanted to implement Vaadin Server push so that changes on the server DB are pushed to users. For example, if User A saves to the server DB, then User B should see the change automatically on his UI.

However, the Vaadin book states that:

> The SQLContainer keeps continuously checking the amount of rows in
>   the connected database table in order to detect external addition or
>   removal of rows. By default, the table row count is assumed to remain
>   valid for 10 seconds. This value can be altered from code; with 
>   setSizeValidMilliSeconds() in SQLContainer.

So does this mean that i dont need to implement server push for server db changes?

Will the SQLContainer also check for row updates?

I believed the reason for server push was to push data changes to users?

Comment: FYI, the `SQLContainer` is has been dropped from Vaadin 8 and later. Some suggest using Java libraries such as MyBatis, jOOQ, or Querydsl as an alternative approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it only checks the row count. You can see that at the source code of SQLContainer's `size()` and `updateCount()` methods. Pushing each DB change to users via push is not a common practice, because it does not scale well. You can put a refresh button to update the container's data or poll the DB for changes periodically, by using the Refresher addon. (https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/refresher)

Comment: i have tried using the refresher add on but is there a general approach to refresh my containers and the UI elements using them? I have a view class with containers but i dont want to access them in a static way from the UI class. @mithridas

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your needs, but the general approach to refreshing containers is by using a button to trigger refresh on a container. On the other hand, if a user action causes the data that your container uses to change (saving a record to a DB table for ex.), you may trigger container to refresh upon user action.

Comment: Another approach is to use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule a recurring task that checks for fresh data in a background thread. When found, that background thread calls the `UI.access` method to update the Vaadin widgets.